# jQuery on-load fadeIn doesn't work for unknown reason

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to make the body appear when the website loads. I tried lots of things but didn't work. I would be grateful for help.

```
var celyLogin = $(".container");

$(document).ready(function(){

    /*! Fades in page on load */
    $(".container").css('display', 'none');
    $(".container").fadeIn(5000);

    });
```

I tried changing from class to id, didn't work. I asked this question once but I had another issue with not putting . before "container". I don't know where's the issue. Please help. Here are CSS and HTML:

```
h1 {
    display: block;
    color: aliceblue;
    text-align: center;
}

body {
    background-color: #0c0c0c;
    font-family: 'Fira Code', monospace;
}

.container {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;

}

.submit {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body class="container">
    <div>
        <div>
         <h1>WELCOME USER</h1>

    <div id="UandP">
        <h3>
            Username: <input class="username" type="text" name="username">
        </h3>

        <h3>
            Password: <input class="password" type="password" name="password">
        </h3>
    </div>

         <input type="button" class="submit" value="Log In" name="submit" onclick="validate()">
    </div>    
</div>

</body>
    <script scr="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script scr="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Take your scripts tags into your body

Comment: First thing to get out of the way, is to move your `<script>` tags at the bottom to be before the `</body>` tag

Comment: You mean those under </body> (jQ, script.js)?

Comment: Yeah, and, probably your real issue, is you have a typo with `scr="..."`.  That should be `src="..."`

Comment: Yeah, that was the issue. Thanks for help @Taplar

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in both of your JavaScript imports. You typed `scr` instead of `src`.

Comment: On another note, I would suggest you update your CSS so that the container has display:none by default. That way it won't be visible for the split second before the $(document).ready function triggers.